# AngularJS Expression usage in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building a simple webpage where I get some JSON data like this:

```
{
"Persons" : [{
        "Initials" : "jd",
        "Name" : "Jhon Doe",
        "Email" : "jd@somemail.com",
        "Title" : "Some title",
        "Phone" : "+999 999 999",
        "PictureUrl" : "personimages/jd.jpg"
    }, {
        "Initials" : "jb",
        "Name" : "James Bond",
        "Email" : "jb@somemail.com",
        "Title" : "Agent",
        "Phone" : "+007 007 007",
        "PictureUrl" : "personimages/jb.jpg"
    }, ...
    ],
"DistLists" : [{
        "ContainedPersons" : ["jd", "jb", ...],
        "Title" : "Some Title"
    }, {
        "ContainedPersons" : ["jd, "hp, ..."],
        "Title" : "Some other Title"
    }, ...
]
}
```

And so I am creating a webpage where you can select the different "Groups" in "DistLists". 
And by selecting the e.g. "Some Title" group I want to take the "ContainedPersons" array, and loop through "Persons" and display the information for all the "Persons" that are in the "ContainedPersons" array.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="WhoIsWho2">
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="app/gemApp.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body ng-controller="WhoIsWho2Controller as wiw2">
      <div class="text-center" ng-controller="myCtrl">
         <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.Title for item in distlist"></select>
         <p>{{selectedItem.ContainedPersons}}</p>

         <table align="center" border="1">
            <tr ng-repeat="ini in selectedItem.ContainedPersons">
               <td>
                  <p ng-repeat="employ in wiw2.employees | filter: {Initials:'{{ini}}'}">Hejsa Test 2 {{employ.Name}} </p>                        
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And my JavaScript file containing angular looks something like this.

```
(function () {
   var app = angular.module('WhoIsWho2', []);

   app.controller('WhoIsWho2Controller', function () {
      this.employees = persons;
   });

   app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.distlist = distlist;
   });
})();
```

Where persons and distlist in the JavaScript file is my data. (Locally now, but should come from the JSON file)

My problem is that I am not allowed to use the {{ini}} in the ng-repeat in my `<p>` element.

Is there another way to achieve this?
Or maybe with another design?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try only ini instead {{ini}}? You are inside angular tag, not is necessary to use mustaches.

Comment: Create a plnkr with Details

Comment: @LucasCosta Thank you! This did the trick, and I had totally overlooked it!

Comment: @RasmusCarlsen you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This :

```
 <tr ng-repeat="ini in selectedItem.ContainedPersons">
   <td>
      <p ng-repeat="employ in wiw2.employees | filter: {Initials:ini}">Hejsa Test 2 {{employ.Name}} </p>                        
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Hi @RasmusCarlsen if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/237701) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.